# How to push an object array into an scop array?

Tags: angularjs

In angular js How can I push an object array into an array.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.Class}}

</h1>
<div ng-repeat="s in records.students">{{s.name}}</div>


  <input ng-model="formdata.name"  type="text" />


            <input type="button"  value="Save" ng-click="saveName(formdata)">
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [{"Class":"Class 8"}];
  $scope.saveName = function(name)
  {
    $scope.records.students.push({"name":name});
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

how can I push into  $scope.records.students here  $scope.records is an array.

what mistake I am doing I am getting "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Answer (score 2):

Your records property on $scope has no property called students. Therefore, `$scope.records.students` is undefined. Undefined doesn't have any methods available. You should make sure students exists before pushing.

Also, be aware the ngModel passes by reference. In your original code, the `{{s.name}}` list will only ever show the text in the input because each element in students points towards the same underlying reference. You should dereference the string that saveName receives. I've done so in the code below, but try playing with it so you can see how it works.

Updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.Class}}

</h1>
<div ng-repeat="s in records.students">{{s.name}}</div>


  <input ng-model="formdata.name"  type="text" />


            <input type="button"  value="Save" ng-click="saveName(formdata)">
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [{"Class":"Class 8"}];
  $scope.saveName = function(name)
  {
    // Also, you need to derefence the object
    // this is a quick and dirty way, try removing it and see
    // what happens
    var deRefName = JSON.stringify(name);
  
    // Checks for the existence of students, if it doesn't exist
    // sets students to an empty array
    if (!($scope.records.students)) {
      $scope.records.students = [];
    }
    
    $scope.records.students.push({"name":deRefName});
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error denotes, there is no way you can access records.students since its an array, not an object.

You need to have records as either an object and inside it student as an array.
then you should be able to access $scope.records.students.

or use $scope.records as array and use index to access the particular object of it.